# Precision of x decimal points in meters?

Tags: gps

Is there a handy reference that corelates the number of decimal points in a coordinate to the precision in meters?

I had discussions like "4 decimal places will place you within a 500 meter radius" and "6 decimal places will place you in a house". I want a reference that can clear up such facts and requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this awesome answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/7913) to a similar question (guessing WGS84 due to the gps tag) and don't forget that false precision can be a big problem if you'll be working on large scales with cheap receivers.

Answer (score 6):

Not unless you can define what the units of measure are: degrees lat/lon, UTM, or some other units.