# Drawing a Satellites Coverage FootPrint on an OpenLayers Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers-2

We have been discussing offering at some point in the future satellite footprints on some of the maps we offer.  Initially the ISS but some Satellites may be appropriate as well. We have also been looking at this in the context of disaster management, and providing some tools for disaster planners to visualize where different useful satellites may be located to assist.

These two [A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77651/how-to-find-ring-of-coverage-of-gps-satellite-on-wgs-84-ellipsoid/77717#77717) and [B](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/bilateration-intersection-of-2-circles/53323#53323) excellent questions provide a great deal of information but are way too complex for my old brain to put into practice.

Would someone be able to show me the correct Openlayers JScript Code to draw the shape of the footprint on a vector layer, given the Satellites position and height.

Accuracy would not be critical as it is a visualization. Maps would be EPSG:4326 and/or EPSG:900913

Comment: Those questions really won't help you out much. The satellite image footprint is more a characteristic of the sensor and the processing, rather than just a function of the satellite. Many satellites will have multiple sensors, and the footprint/swath  of the different data products is different.

Comment: Valid points, I had not considered the sensor shape. hmmm, the idea was to give a representative view of where a satellite may be overhead and of use. I guess it would be reasonable that we would be interested in a visual image, now that you mention it, the LandSat images I have seen are rectangular or at least shown that way. That is also a function then of the direction of travel of the Satellite as well. Perhaps we maybe better off determining which birds may be of use in a disaster and drawing the correct footprint from that on a per satellite basis.