# How to draw polygons in shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

How do I draw a polygon in a shapefile that I've created from joined points of 2 .csv files?

Which specific tool do I use?

Comment: What does your data look like? Any common attribute for the points that make up each polygon (and order)? Could you post a sample of your data? I'm guessing that you currently have a shapefile with only points?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828905/polygon-enclosing-a-set-of-points , "convex hull" is a search term you can employ.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: Hi Poly Geo, thanks for writing back! I'm working with QGIS 2.2.0.   I'm following directions from this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113967/how-do-i-plot-points-that-have-relative-coordinates-rather-than-total-station-co/113988?noredirect=1#comment163772_113988

Comment: The CSV file looks like this:                               point corner dist Basket
1 174-204 5 1198018
1 174-205 3.95 1198018
2 174-304 5.08 1496022
2 174-204 1.94 1496022
3 174-207 5.38 1498100
3 174-307 2.9 1498100
4 151-2006 4.4 16D93D010
4 151-2007 3.95 16D93D010
5 151-2006 5.07 16D93D011
5 151-2007 2.63 16D93D011
6 174-208 1.37 16D04B044
6 174-209 3.75 16D04B044

Comment: Please re-upload your snippet of CSV data to http://pastebin.com or https://gist.github.com so that the original line formatting stays intact

Answer (score 2):

In QGis, use the "convex hull" tool from the vector submenu.

From the points shown this creates the following polygons:
[image: Input points]
[image: Result of convex hull]

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new shapefile of type polygon. The points layer can only contain points.

If you set snapping on the point layer, the vertices of the polygon will exactly hit your points.