# Finding Intersection of Two Circle given Lat/Lon and radius?

Tags: javascript, intersection, circle, mathematics

I am attempting to calculate the intersection of two circle on the Earth with a given latitude, longitude and radius. I started with this [Calculating intersection of two Circles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-2-circles)

These circles will never be more than 100 km in diameter and will normally be "close" to each other, meaning two intersecting points for the pair of circles.

I added a comment in the code below at the place where I am having the issue.

I originally asked this question on StackOverflow, but with this being so geospatial, I did not get any answers.

```
var circle1 = {lat:37.673442, lon:-90.234036, r:107.5};
var circle2 = {lat:36.109997, lon:-90.953669, r:145};

function findInterscetionOfTwoCircles(circle1, circle2){
    var c1 = latLonToGeocentricCoords(circle1);
    var c2 = latLonToGeocentricCoords(circle2);
    var r1 = convertRadius(circle1.r);
    var r2 = convertRadius(circle2.r);
    var c1dotc2 = calculateDotProduct(c1, c2);

    // This is where the problem is occurring.
    // The value of 'a' should be 0.9735030 but I am getting 46.770178816522844.
    // I am certain that r1 and r2 are correct (match the values in the original post). Additionally, I believe the calculateDotProduct function to be
    // correct, therefore making c1dotc2 correct. I think I have ruled out
    // any Order of Operations error. Maybe it is a degree/radian conversion
    // issue or something like it? I tried different variations and I  and now out
    // of ideas.
    var a = (Math.cos(r1) - (Math.cos(r2) * c1dotc2)) / (1 - (c1dotc2 * c1dotc2)); 
    var b = (Math.cos(r2) - (Math.cos(r1) * c1dotc2)) / (1 - (c1dotc2 * c1dotc2)); 
    // -45.83805010474024, should be  0.0260194
    var n = calculateCrossProduct(c1, c2); 

    var x0 = calculateLinearCombination(a, b, c1, c2);

    var ndotn = calculateDotProduct(n, n);

    // var t = Math.sqrt((1 - calculateDotProduct(x0,x0))/calculateDotProduct(n,n));

    // Finish the algorithm
}

function latLonToGeocentricCoords(circle){
    var x = Math.cos(degToRad(circle.lon)) * Math.cos(degToRad(circle.lat));
    var y = Math.sin(degToRad(circle.lon)) * Math.cos(degToRad(circle.lat));
    var z = Math.sin(degToRad(circle.lat));

    return {x:x, y:y, z:z};
}

function geocentricCoordsToLatLon(x, y, z){
    var lon = Math.atan2(x,y)
    var lat = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)), z)

    return { lat: lat, lon: lon};
}

function convertRadius(radius){
    // converts NM right now
    return degToRad(radius) / 60; 
}

function calculateDotProduct(input1, input2){
    if(arguments.length !== 2){
        throw new Error('You must supply two arguments to this method.');
    }

    if(Array.isArray(input1) !== Array.isArray(input2) || typeof input1 !== typeof input2){
        throw new Error('Inputs must be the same types.');
    }

    var dotProduct = 0;
    if(Array.isArray(input1)){
        // process as parallel arrays
        if(input1.length === input2.length){
            throw new Error('Input lengths must be the same.');
        }
        for(var i = 0, len = input1.length; i < len; i++){
            dotProduct += input1[i] * input2[i];
        }
    } else if(typeof input1 === 'object' && !Array.isArray(input1)){
        // process as key-value object
        for(var key in input1){
            if (input1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if(!input2[key]){
                    throw new Error('Both inputs must have the same properties to be processed.');
                }
                dotProduct += input1[key] * input2[key];
            }

        }
    }

    return dotProduct; 
}

function calculateCrossProduct(circle1, circle2){
    var x = (circle1.y * circle2.z) - (circle1.z * circle2.y);
    var y = (circle1.z * circle2.x) - (circle1.x * circle2.z);
    var z = (circle1.x * circle2.y) - (circle1.y * circle2.x);

    return {x: x, y: y, z: z};
}

function calculateLinearCombination(a, b, c1, c2){
    var x = {x: a * c1.x, y: a * c1.y, z: a * c1.z};
    var y = {x: b * c2.x, y: b * c2.y, z: b * c2.z};

    return calculateDotProduct(x, y);
} 

function degToRad(degree){
    return degree * Math.PI / 180;
}

function radToDeg(radian){
    return radian / Math.PI * 180;
}
```

Comment: you have mentioned radius as r=107.5 and r=145. Is radius in km or m? If 'r' is in km then how diameter will be less than 100 km?

Comment: The units in nautical miles.

Comment: `Math.cos` etc. [expect their arguments to be in radians, not degrees.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos).  However, your function `convertRadians` clearly does not return radians (nor does it even return "NM", if that's intended to be nautical miles).

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the feedback. Based on what you said, I realized my mistake and was able to correct it. The name of the name was just a typo, but in the `convertRadius` function I was multiplying by 6 instead of 60. Anyways, your feedback (and you original post) was extremely helpful.

Answer (score -2):

circle1 with r=107.5 naut.mile and circle2 with r=145 naut.mile intersect at points as shown in the image:
[image]

One should adopt projected (Cartesian) coordinate system for this type of work. I have worked on UTM-Zone 15 because both circle center lie in this zone. If u try to do this manually/mathematically using polar coordinate system, it will be much complicated due to imperfect earth shape. One can perform more accurate calculation by adopting best projection/coordinate system for this area.