# Doing high-fidelity trilateration in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, software-recommendations, trilateration

Is there a way to do high-fidelity trilateration in R (naturally, I'll be using latitudes and longitudes)?

I'm not looking to solve a specific problem, but rather identify tools that are capable of doing this. To my knowledge, classic packages like `geosophere` `sf` and `sp` don't have this capability. Robert Hijams made his own implementation at [Calculating intersection of two Circles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48937), but the output of `geophere` lon/lats only go out to 5 decimal places, whereas I would like something that has 6 decimal places.

For those looking for background on trilateration, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) is simple intro.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you've got code that works to 5 decimal places, a good question might be "How do I do this [...] but to 6 or more decimal places?" It might be that its only printing 5 decimal places, but unless you show a code example we can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spacedman pointed out, `R` is just not printing out all the decimal places. I feel silly for not having thought of that given the amount of time I spend in `R`, but then again, I rarely think 6 decimal places out! Here is Robert's code (linked in original post), but with options for more decimal places:

```
p1 <- cbind(-90.234036, 37.673442) 
p2 <- cbind(-90.953669, 36.109997 )

library(geosphere)
steps <- seq(0, 360, 0.1)
c1 <- destPoint(p1, steps, 107.5 * 1852)
c2 <- destPoint(p2, steps, 145 * 1852)

library(raster)
s1 <- spLines(c1)
s2 <- spLines(c2)

i <- intersect(s1, s2)
coordinates(i)

#        x        y
# -92.38241 38.24267
# -88.15830 36.98740

s <- bind(s1, s2)
crs(s) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
plot(s)
points(i, col='red', pch=20, cex=2)



options(digits=20)
coordinates(i)

                          x                     y
#[1,] -92.382414938640280866 38.242669773141031442
#[2,] -88.158303526976155240 36.987395741226784196
```