# convert GPS to XY coordinates

Tags: convert, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

if i have obtain GPS coordinates as Latitude/Longitude, then i need to convert them to XY coordinates, i see this [link](http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=LatLon&to=XY)

actually i need to get the [Trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) , in its equation i need the XY coordinates from GPS coordinates.

i need obvious and clear equation for conversion.

also how the conversion will be if i assume there is reference node !!

my application is :

i need to make Trilateration for sensor nodes and in the middle of the there is pc which get positions of nodes(depends on gps) then pc can calculate its position depend on Trilateration. So  Trilateration equation  use XY rather than lat/lon ?? can we use the pc as reference node to conversion.

Comment: In order to convert from `lat/lon` to X/Y, you need to choose a [Map Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) and [Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system) based on that projection.  What is your actual project?  Trilateration is a means to an end, but what will you be using the points for?  A word of warning about the conversion link:  There is no information about the basis of conversion.  This can vary significantly depending on the location of the points, and your intended use.  Adding more detail will probably help you get a better answer.

Comment: i need to make Trilateration for sensor nodes and in the middle of the there is pc which get positions of nodes(depends oon gps) then pc can calculate its position depend on Trilateration.
So in Trilateration equation i need to use XY rather than lat/lon ??
can we use the pc as reference node to conversion.

Comment: QGIS (and probably all other GIS packages) does such conversions, has full details of the reference systems it uses, and a huge variety of them available for use.

Comment: @Hanaa please don't add comments when clarification is requested. Instead select the edit button and modify the original question. You can mark the new section with EDIT:

Comment: Do you really need trilateration (e.g. are you working from the GPS pseudoranges) or are you just asking http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58052/convert-gps-to-x-y-using-reference-node again? How about actually showing us the real data?

Comment: actually i get the lat/lon data but when i need to do trilateration i need the XY equal to do this operation,

mm i need to get the unknown position through the known position (GPS) via doing trilateration