# display latitude and longitude on googlemaps on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I am trying to retrieve latitude and longitude values. When the user clicks on the google map, latitude and longitude values should be displayed in the text boxes.

My code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Show Google Map with Latitude and Longitude in asp.net website</title>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.18061975930,79.36565089010);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom:7,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
        // marker refers to a global variable
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        });
        // if center changed then update lat and lon document objects
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
            var location = map.getCenter();
            document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = location.lat();

            document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = location.lng();
            // call function to reposition marker location
            placeMarker(location);
        });
        // if zoom changed, then update document object with new info
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
            document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = zoomLevel;
        });
        // double click on the marker changes zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom() + 1;
            if (zoomLevel == 20) {
                zoomLevel = 10;
            }
            document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = zoomLevel;
            map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
        });

        function placeMarker(location) {
            var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
            marker.setPosition(location);
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () { initialize() };
</script>
     <style>
 div#gmap {
        width: 80%;
        height: 500px;
        border:double;
 }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<center>
<!-- MAP HOLDER -->
<div id="gmap"></div>
<!-- REFERENCES -->

lat:
lon:

</center>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

But it not displaying anything. Please tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: Detail blog:http://goo.gl/pDD6Q8

Answer (score 6):

In the following lines you are trying to refer to a DOM element that does not exist:

```
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = location.lat();
document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = location.lng();
```

So in your HTML you would have to add an element like a **div** or a **span**, that you can give an *id*. I would use a span, so you can stay in the same line without any further work:

```
lat:<span id='lat'></span>
lon:<span id='lon'></span>
```

Now your code grabs the element and writes the result into it.

[image]

**EDIT**:
But is that actually what you want to do? Pan the map and display its current coordinates? Or do you want to get the coordinates of your current click?

**EDIT 2**: (addressing comments):

Here would be your JavaScript (I have omitted what is not necessary to answer the question)

```
    var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.18061975930,79.36565089010);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:7,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
            // marker refers to a global variable
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
                // get lat/lon of click
                var clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
                var clickLon = event.latLng.lng();

                // show in input box
                document.getElementById("lat").value = clickLat.toFixed(5);
                document.getElementById("lon").value = clickLon.toFixed(5);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickLat,clickLon),
                        map: map
                     });
            });
    }   

    window.onload = function () { initialize() };
```

And this you would add to your body:

```
Lat: <input type="text" id='lat'>
Lon: <input type="text" id='lon'>
```

**NOTE** that I have truncated the decimals in the window using *toFixed(5)*, as it does not make sense to display [too many decimals](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude).

As your next step you should probably remove all existing markers when clicking. You can use [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) to implement that.

Comment: yes i want to get coordinates of current click , and also i want to display the coordinates in textboxes,and also i tried with span but i want that values in textbox.in the above example user has to move the map near marker but for me user has to click on the map there marker has to be displayed and also coordiantes in textbox.                       plz send me the full code bcoz iam trying from so many days

Comment: By textbox you mean this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

?

Comment: plz see this link   http://www.latlong.net/                           i want exactly like this

Comment: See my edits. This implements the basic functionality you are asking for. You'd have to go ahead and add some things to make it more user-friendly, of course.