# Transfer from Android phone to Windows OS truncates lat long

Tags: gps, coordinates, accuracy, precision

I am clicking GPS enabled pictures of sites which are less than 500 metres apart through Android based Samsung ACE Duos phone. I later use Google Earth on my Laptop  to view these geo tagged pictures. I am facing a problem that Windows Vista OS on my laptop truncates the lat long to six places after decimal. This I realised after seeing the Properties of the transferred JPG file in Laptop. However, in the original picture  the details of the jpg when checked in Gallery of the phone shows 12/15 digits after decimal.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you explain why the extra digits are truncated. Instead I suggest they do not matter; a decimal co-ordinate with 6 digits is accurate to <0.1m. See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/24270 or the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: Furthermore all those digits in the phone data are just false accuracy/precision, since the unit in the phone probably isn't good to better than 3m anyway. Whatever software you're using to actually bring the photos over probably knows this and is rounding. Further, the way that data is stored (float, double) and with how many bytes also plays a role. More precision means more space, so while the metadata probably stores it as a string, when converted to a numeric it doesn't have room for all those extra digits.

Comment: @ChrisW I used blue tooth to transfer the file from phone. The lat shown on phone was  27.496607716352873. I transferred the picture on the laptop.   When I used Exif Viewer online to view the lat of picture on laptop the lat became 27.496389. I require at least 4 decimal digits accuracy. Please guide.

Comment: @pankaj365 If you're just copying a file and there's no software processing going on, I have no idea why it would *change*. While you have six digits there, which should cover your accuracy requirement, I note the example values you provide are neither truncated or rounded - they are *different* at the fourth decimal. That could be explained by two consecutive readings from the phone, since as I said it's probably not that accurate, but I see no reason that a captured and recorded value should change just by copying a file. You may need to pursue the phone's technical documentation or support.