# Breaking up 50mb KML file to under 10mb files?

Tags: kml

I have a large 50mb KML file and we would like the file to be broken into smaller KML files so they can be placed on ArcMap.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/whats-next-if-our-kml-is-too-big-complex-for-the-google-maps-api) and [that](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143820/reducing-size-of-kml-file-after-converting-from-shapefile)

Answer (score 4):

KML is a XML type document. Which can be manipulated with any means you'd manipulate XML files (even notepad can).

Say you have this sample file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>New York City</name>
    <description>New York City</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-74.006393,40.714172,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>New York City 2</name>
    <description>New York City dummy</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-74,40,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Every kml file may only have one `<kml>` tag,which encompasses everything else. It also needs the `<?xml` header (first line). That is all.

So the split files could look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>New York City</name>
    <description>New York City</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-74.006393,40.714172,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>New York City 2</name>
    <description>New York City dummy</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-74,40,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

If the manual splitting is too tedious, it can also be done in the scripting language of your choice (e.g. python/arcPy), almost every one offers a way to process XML files by default. However, for questions regarding automated XML processing you'll find a lot more information already on http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Open them in Google Earth Pro. Select portions and move or copy to new folders. When re-arranged appropriately. Right click on folder and save save as new place. Choose this location. Band repeat four different folders.

It should be noted that this reasoning for this is not needed. ArcMap can convert kml/kmz files of much greater size.