# How to anonymise a gps file?

Tags: r, gps, gpx, simplify

Imagine you have a GPS trace that you want to make anonymous, in the legal sense. How would you do this? Is snapping to the nearest x distance and stripping out the time enough? Are there internationally agreed standards on this? Has anyone already written an algorithm to do this? If not I plan to make a function in my evolving [stplanr package](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/issues/5) to do this.

Reproducible example (using [awesome rotation function](http://rpubs.com/geospacedman/rotatespatial) from @geospacedman) from my own '[Identifiable](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/RobinLovelace/traces/1619756)' data:

```
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
downloader::download("https://www.openstreetmap.org/trace/1619756/data", "test.gpx")

r <-readOGR(dsn = "test.gpx", layer = "tracks")
r <- spTransform(r, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
rproj <- rotateProj(rs, 90) # rotate projection for plotting
r <- spTransform(r, rproj)
rs <- rgeos::gSimplify(r, 1000) # snap to nearest km
qtm(r) + qtm(rs, line.col = "red") + tm_layout(draw.frame = F) + tm_scale_bar()
```

[image: red-route]

The result is shown above. In summary: is the red route 'identifiable' and is there a better way?

Comment: I think you may need a good definition and scope for what is "anonymous" here. This will depend hugely on the context of the data, e.g. if its in a city, anyone could have followed even a very precise route, in a remote/restricted area it gives away a lot more info if it starts/ends at or goes through a particularly informative location (e.g. someone's house). And what information needs to be retained? distance travelled? relative times or velocity? the path for mapping out a trail? These will determine whether you can simply remove (some) data, or add constant/random noise for example.

Comment: what do you plan to use it for matters too, you could just set the start point to 0,0 for all your routes

Comment: Interesting question and am dealing with some similar issues with shared cycling data. Are you imagining 'anonymising' a __GPX__ file and keeping it in GPX format? Could you save as a line (discarding trackpoint info)? What do you really want to obscure?

Comment: Discussion with colleagues has led to the idea of simply chopping the first and last x metres to a distance which is deemed 'k anonymous' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-anonymity . In answer to @drfrogsplat I mean the ICO's defintion of anonymity, which is vague: "There is no simple rule for handling spatial information – such 
as postcodes, GPS data or map references - under the Data 
Protection Act 1998 (DPA). In some circumstances this will 
constitute personal data" (but which?): https://ico.org.uk/media/1061/anonymisation-code.pdf

Comment: What is K anonymity is for a __sequence__ of GPS points? What do you mean by 'chopping' the first/last metres - you mean trimming the set of points (shorter), or reducing the accuracy of the trackpoints?

Comment: @Simbamangu I mean by 'clipping' cutting off the beginning and end of the track. I'm not sure what K anonymity is for a sequence of points. Thanks for the clarifying questions, hope they help.

Comment: could you make an adjustment to the X and Y coordinate of each point by a random distance between a certain minimum and maximum offset? and also make the direction of the offset (plus or minus) a random selection. Include in the randomisation that some points may have no adjustment to one or both parts of a coordinate pair.

Comment: @Adam yes that would be a possibility

Comment: @RobinLovelace great! do that then!

Answer (score 5):

I'm working with our local cycling group to anonymise GPX files on two criteria (primarily for security). I've never come across a standard way of anonymising data but this satisfies two concerns of our members, while preserving accuracy along roads and speed information:

- Personal locations, removing 'private' areas for individuals;
- Obscuring timestamps so that travel data could not be used to identify individual movements.

GPSBabel can do both of these from the command line - for example, to shift the times in a GPX file by +123450 seconds, and remove all trackpoints 0.5 km away from a landmark in northern Tanzania:

```
gpsbabel -t -i gpx -f infile.gpx \
  -x transform,wpt=trk,del -x track,move=123450s \
  -x radius,distance=0.5K,lat=-3.368,lon=36.624,nosort,exclude \
  -x transform,trk=wpt,del \
  -o gpx -F infile_rand.gpx
```

- `-t`: process tracks only;
- `-i`, `-f`: input file type (gpx) and filename;
- `-x`: two sequential (-x) filter arguments for timeshift (move) and removal (radius,exclude) around a point;
- `-o`, `-F`: output file type and filename.

This command [chains together several filters](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_filters_with_GPSBabel) - first transforming the trackpoints into waypoints, then filtering, then transforming back to trackpoints.

Note that reducing the decimal places around the landmark / privacy area is VERY important as it obscures the exact centre of the privacy area. 3 decimal places = [~ 110m accuracy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/4892) in this case.

I usually call GPSBabel from R, writing a new GPX file with filters applied, including a random timeshift +/- 2 weeks. This would be better as a bash or python script but a lot of the other work I do is in R and I'm lazy ...

```
# Get the correct location for GPSBabel:
GB <- Sys.which("gpsbabel")

# Set up the filters
shift <- round((runif(1, 0, 2600000) - 1300000), 0) # +/- 2 weeks in secs
filter <- " -x transform,wpt=trk,del"
filter <- paste(" -x track,move=", shift, "s", sep = "")
filter <- paste(filter, " -x radius,distance=", dist, "K,", "lat=", lat, ",long=", lon, sep = "")
filter <- paste(filter, " -x transform,wpt=trk,del", sep="")

# Pass the complete command to the system
system(paste(GB, " -t -i gpx -f ", gpx_file, filter, " -o gpx -F ", 
           gsub(".gpx", replacement = "_rand.gpx", x = gpx_file, fixed = T),
           sep = ""), intern = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck, this is tremendously hard to do! If you are serious about it you should read about differential privacy because this is probably what you are after.

When you think of this problem, you should consider the case of a recluse person living at the end of long isolated road. Do you really think you can do something about their GPS coordinate and not reveal anything about that particular person. The side information here is that it can be easily discovered that only one person lives there.

Stripping the user Id, the time and adding noise to the data points is a good place to start.
But the problem is that all the datapoints are heavily correlated so if you add random noise to each point the noise will cancel out and someone will be able to derive the likely trajectories. So the noise would have to be resistant to this attack, for instance by making it constant over a trajectory. But then, trajectories can probably be easily matched with likely routes based on roads, etc.

I am not sure if the data you will end up with will still be workable for whatever you want to do with it but at least it is a passionating field.

PS: I don't know about legally acceptable, I would expect it to be a moving target and country specific while the mathematical definition of differential privacy is the most robust you can get.

Answer (score 0):

make an adjustment to the X and Y coordinate of each point by a random distance between a certain minimum and maximum offset. also make the direction of the offset (plus or minus) a random selection. Include in the randomisation that some points may have no adjustment to one or both parts of a coordinate pair.