# Shortest and longest amount of numbers that latitude and longitudinal coordinates may have?

Tags: latitude-longitude

What is the shortest and longest amount of numbers that latitude and longitudinal coordinates may have?

For instance i know that London is 51.5072 0.1275. So the first value is 6 numbers and the second is 4 (or 5 depending on how you look at it).

Comment: For the "shortest" amount: there is a location at 0.0 0.0, as such, depending on your definitions, zero , one or two numbers.

Comment: Real values do not have limits, but there are scale-appropriate boundaries. Latitude is bounded by 90S (-90.0) and 90N (+90.0), but longitude is unbounded (1000W is valid, though it could be represented by smaller values). I'll generally use "12.6" formatting on degrees, which provides precision to ~11cm, but if I know the collection protocol has much less precision, I'll use fewer digits to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically the precision is unlimited. You could very well say that 51.5072321685498474643544 0.127556181987987156543154 is a point somewhere in London. However it rarely makes sense to use such a high precision. File formats and tools often have hard-coded limits of precision. If not by the format itself then by the data type used internally. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers for an introduction in number representation in computer systems.

Usually you are only interested in a precision up to a certain degree (pun intended!). So first decide how many digits you actually need or utilise, then use one more for safety.

Check [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) or the Wikipedia article on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees for more information and conversions to meters.

Comment: +0.5 for the answer and +0.5 for the pun!