# How much is the error in physical longitude and lagitude (e.g. meters) corresponding to a +-0.0001 error in GPS coordinates?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, accuracy, precision

If I have a device how give-me a latitude and longitude with 7 decimals (eg. -42.5124478, -22.3006726, longitude and latitude respectively ) and I round it to 4 decimals (eg. -42.5124, -22.3007).

It represents +-0.0001 of possible precision error.

[image]

The point is, imagining about a Earth a perfect sphere, I want to know what max limits from rounded decimals in Earth Surface according of rounding (based on this metric answered here [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)

how much dislocation of surface area it will represents? and how to calculate it?

Comment: This will depend on the latitude of your area of interest. A degree (or a fraction of it) represents a larger distance near the Equator than near the Poles

Comment: This has been answered in depth already, e.g. in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Yes, but not so depth enough.

I think it's not a duplicate question, its totally different than about know "how much is latitude in meters" or "How to measure the accuracy of latitude and longitude?"

The point is, imagining about a Earth a perfect sphere, I want to know what max limits from rounded decimals (for this i make a example of rounding of 7 to 4 degrees ) in Earth Surface. It's possible? The other questions that you mark as duplicate or suggest me doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Your device is likely giving you more precision than what its true accuracy is. From the linked Q&A, 4th decimal place, 11 m approximately and that's calculated from 1 degree = 111 km at the equator.

Comment: @mkennedy The device could be anything (eg. [UAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle) or [UCAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_combat_aerial_vehicle)) and may are using a [DGPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS)  to provide a best accurancy . 
A combined distortion of lat and lng +- 0.0001 could be fatal.