# Radius in nn2() in RANN package

Tags: r, distance, latitude-longitude, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I was trying to use the solution offered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213971/units-for-radius-in-nn2-in-rann-package) to find all the location from `df` which are within the 70 km distance from my point of interest `userLocation=c(6.9,55,2)`, but it does not work properly.

```
    df = structure(list(lng = c(6.2694184, 6.25737207, 6.23839104, 6.25844252, 
6.22595901, 6.21351832, 6.2010845, 6.1886414, 6.1762058, 6.1637609, 
6.15132287, 6.13887619, 6.12643637, 6.14361895, 6.16332364, 6.18302157, 
6.2027276, 6.22242688, 6.24213488, 6.26842752, 6.26745135, 6.24518597, 
6.26645948, 6.24420242, 6.22357831, 6.26548171, 6.24321746, 6.2226023, 
6.20041884, 6.18070459, 6.16099845, 6.16716672, 6.17960629, 6.18686265, 
6.2078525, 6.19203657, 6.20447434, 6.21691835, 6.2293537, 6.24179593, 
6.26009321, 6.26448764, 6.2422317, 6.21927538, 6.20186455, 6.26350828, 
6.24124514, 6.22028969, 6.26251321, 6.2402584, 6.23404584, 6.26153227, 
6.22171658, 5.94065657, 6.10363006, 6.11606487, 6.12850589, 6.14093826, 
6.15337749, 6.16582359, 6.17826103, 6.19070472, 6.20313974, 6.20009703, 
5.96044213, 5.96988333, 5.98023582, 5.98966667, 5.99910246, 6.00003829, 
6.00947365, 6.01889843, 6.02832882, 6.01983402, 6.02925771, 6.038687, 
6.0481219, 6.05754688, 6.03963788, 6.04906608, 6.05848435, 6.06792377, 
6.07735326, 6.08677283, 6.05941948, 6.06885218, 6.07829049, 6.08771889, 
6.09713671, 6.10657633, 6.11600538, 6.07922538, 6.08864707, 6.10756108, 
6.12000483, 6.13243993, 6.12019786, 6.14488189, 6.15733073, 6.16977091, 
6.16621949, 6.13805015, 6.13652024, 5.941545, 6.20491484, 6.18423897, 
6.17806466, 6.16355552, 6.15738696, 6.14558294, 6.14286638, 6.13670293, 
6.12217027, 6.11601258, 6.10148275, 6.09533146, 6.08080511, 6.07464337, 
6.06011984, 6.03729438, 6.05394895, 6.02546329, 6.0136389, 6.03674112, 
6.05743408, 6.07812006, 6.09879971, 6.11948795, 6.11063647, 6.08914275, 
6.08440881, 6.0018212, 6.02491713, 5.98999461, 6.01308427, 5.97815849, 
6.00125809, 5.96632973, 5.98943792, 5.9995124, 6.02119838, 6.04364466, 
6.0223476, 6.04560587, 6.03821257, 6.06131821, 6.06046748, 5.97888909, 
5.95766873, 6.24771247, 6.04931495, 6.25538943, 6.23227728, 6.25434093, 
6.25329159, 6.25225759, 6.25120656, 6.25015469, 6.24911757, 6.06338238, 
6.08539205, 6.10756976, 6.12975108, 6.15193667, 6.17411029, 6.19630377, 
6.21848591, 6.22602495, 6.23123663, 6.20931486, 6.23019515, 6.20826628, 
6.22915282, 6.20721685, 6.22810966, 6.21962063, 6.20209266, 6.20618216, 
6.19702482, 6.1799057, 6.15772301, 6.13554395, 6.11336914, 6.09118237, 
6.09738412, 6.11958004, 6.12698723, 6.14767387, 6.16835417, 6.18613747, 
6.185096, 6.165456, 6.14476821, 6.15765091, 6.23561071, 6.08001353, 
6.22353732, 6.2376767, 6.21143885, 6.19936347, 6.18727866, 6.17520066, 
6.16311385, 6.15103386, 6.13894506, 6.12686243, 6.11478725, 6.10270261, 
6.09818625, 6.12128852, 6.2468456, 6.22571713, 6.24558662, 6.22445138, 
6.24434288, 6.22320086, 6.24308194, 6.22194875, 6.24182062, 6.22068065, 
6.24057332, 6.21942655, 6.2113264, 6.22341814, 6.19699748, 6.18490568, 
6.1988361, 6.17283631, 6.16074252, 6.14867115, 6.13657473, 6.13954049, 
6.16263694, 6.18482009, 6.20327221, 6.20009595, 6.19278885, 6.17005571
), lat = c(54.67598304, 54.83924292, 54.83162024, 54.82483795, 
54.82033259, 54.80904336, 54.79775292, 54.78646988, 54.77517665, 
54.76389082, 54.75260377, 54.74131515, 54.73002531, 54.72096456, 
54.71392047, 54.70687309, 54.69983176, 54.69278713, 54.68573957, 
54.68934722, 54.7027117, 54.69910571, 54.71606682, 54.71246092, 
54.70614626, 54.72943123, 54.72582507, 54.71951053, 54.71576339, 
54.72280423, 54.72985112, 54.74274399, 54.75402944, 54.73569581, 
54.72983408, 54.7653223, 54.77660496, 54.78789538, 54.79918423, 
54.81047187, 54.80230996, 54.74279524, 54.73918917, 54.74155047, 
54.75043676, 54.75615956, 54.75255324, 54.75849353, 54.76951451, 
54.76590829, 54.77879358, 54.78287875, 54.84106585, 54.79004116, 
54.73264696, 54.7439301, 54.755221, 54.76651031, 54.77779842, 
54.78908531, 54.80037062, 54.81166369, 54.82295519, 54.83631649, 
54.78306731, 54.79535153, 54.77609951, 54.7883729, 54.80065457, 
54.76912877, 54.78140068, 54.7936805, 54.80595963, 54.7621547, 
54.77443373, 54.78671208, 54.79898973, 54.81126633, 54.75518666, 
54.76746422, 54.77974071, 54.7920169, 54.80429202, 54.81656608, 
54.74821493, 54.76049101, 54.7727664, 54.78504073, 54.79732298, 
54.80959594, 54.82187682, 54.74124062, 54.75351485, 54.76118719, 
54.77247897, 54.78376916, 54.79513973, 54.79505815, 54.80634591, 
54.8176321, 54.8309898, 54.82587825, 54.81251828, 54.80340625, 
54.85043439, 54.85669012, 54.84379843, 54.8629602, 54.85006754, 
54.83850747, 54.86921769, 54.85633303, 54.87548056, 54.86259492, 
54.88174916, 54.86885358, 54.88800555, 54.8751176, 54.89427628, 
54.89688611, 54.88137801, 54.88534048, 54.87379377, 54.87235508, 
54.86608859, 54.85982748, 54.85356275, 54.84730376, 54.83491117, 
54.82992904, 54.84309445, 54.86224596, 54.86080945, 54.85069668, 
54.84926234, 54.8391549, 54.83771415, 54.82760306, 54.82617384, 
54.81401612, 54.81866848, 54.82193287, 54.83203, 54.85454492, 
54.8418856, 54.84463218, 54.83126946, 54.807705, 54.81314447, 
54.95082492, 54.90870481, 54.85261135, 54.8544958, 54.86597391, 
54.87933643, 54.89269028, 54.90605271, 54.91941509, 54.93277779, 
54.91930405, 54.92337651, 54.92712528, 54.93087901, 54.93462874, 
54.93838307, 54.94213376, 54.94588009, 54.93325056, 54.86785843, 
54.86365241, 54.88122101, 54.87701472, 54.89458354, 54.890377, 
54.90794604, 54.9204011, 54.92916856, 54.90373959, 54.91606989, 
54.92541899, 54.92166542, 54.91791682, 54.91416421, 54.91041621, 
54.89753741, 54.90128459, 54.88863077, 54.8823668, 54.87609923, 
54.88468492, 54.89804726, 54.89094652, 54.89720452, 54.90830415, 
55.08370977, 54.93641839, 55.07226944, 55.06170442, 55.06083624, 
55.04939327, 55.03795778, 55.02652115, 55.01508302, 55.00364374, 
54.99220296, 54.98077001, 54.96932695, 54.95789135, 54.94469353, 
54.94333719, 54.96418243, 54.9585686, 54.97754901, 54.9719349, 
54.99090692, 54.98529252, 55.00427341, 54.99865908, 55.01763087, 
55.01201625, 55.03099761, 55.02538271, 55.03790915, 55.04934232, 
55.02208092, 55.01064489, 54.99998971, 54.99920808, 54.98776941, 
54.97632995, 54.9648976, 54.95153594, 54.95007267, 54.95382515, 
54.96186591, 54.98662348, 54.97394968, 54.97118391)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-238L))
```

What I have done is as follow :
Add the point of interest to the beginning of `df`

```
df = rbind(userLocation,df)
```

Set the radius to 0.64 since according to [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213971/units-for-radius-in-nn2-in-rann-package), every 0.1 is equivalent to 11.1 km !

```
radius <- 0.64
      #Identifying neighbors
      res <- nn2(df, k=nrow(df), searchtype="radius", radius = radius)
```

Since my point of interest is the first row in `df` I would expect all the non zero index in the first row are the points within my 70 km threshold
Ind <- res$nn.idx[1,][res$nn.idx[1,]>0]

My `Ind` object has just one  value! but if I plot the data, all of the points are within 70 km distance :

[image]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is "do you have any locations meeting your query"? When testing this, the answer is no.

```
df <- rbind(c(6.9, 55), df)
radius <- 0.64
res.idx <- RANN::nn2(data=df, query=df, k=nrow(df), 
      searchtype="radius", radius = radius)$nn.idx
  res.idx[1,]    

( d <- as.numeric(as.matrix(dist(df))[,1]) )
  d[d<=0] <- NA
  which(d <= radius)
  min(d,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Your minimum distance is 0.6541357 so, you are not meeting the conditions of your query. If you change your distance threshold, you do return results.

```
radius = 0.80
res.idx <- RANN::nn2(data=df, query=df, k=nrow(df), 
      searchtype="radius", radius = radius)$nn.idx
  res.idx[1,]
```

Recheck our distance vector `which(d <= radius)` and we have matching results.

However, given the distortions (distance non-uniformity) in distance that you will see in a geographic projection, I would highly recommend transforming your data into a projected (distance based) coordinated system or using functions that account for the spherical geometry. Here we can illustrate how your analysis is going wrong without accounting for the spherical geometry (requires the s2 and sf libraries).

```
sdf <- s2::s2_geog_point(df[,1],df[,2])
  d <- s2::s2_distance_matrix(sdf,sdf)[1,] / 1000
which(d <= 70)
  length(which(d <= 70))
  nrow(df)
```

Low and behold, all of your observations are within 70KM. The direct call to s2 is the same as using the sf library

```
library(sf)
sf_use_s2()

sdf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lng", "lat"), 
                crs = 4326, agr = "constant")
 d <- st_distance(sdf)[1,]
   units(d) <- units::as_units("km")
 which(as.numeric(d) <= 70)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is exactly my confusion ! as you see on the map screenshot all of my `df` locations are within the 70 km distance from the `userLocation` object. What is confusing me is the unit for the `radius` parameter in `nn2` command. Is that correct that every 0.1 unit in `radius` represent 11.1 km ?! on the other word what should I choose as `radius` which returns me all the neighbours with in the 70 km distance ?