# How can I exclude POINTs that are x distance from each other?

Tags: postgis

I have a FCC database of antennas and a map view having a bounds. I want to display all antennas within the view, but antennas a stones throw away are duplicates or noise. In the example below, rows 2 and 3 are so close its a dupe (Technically it isn't a dupe, but it is noise.). How can I do a SELECT and filter out antennas that are close (x meters) from each other?

```
SELECT distinct st_astext(geom), ST_Distance(loc.geom::geography, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-115.62309833 35.97311)', 4326)::geography) / 1609.344 as miles
FROM fcc_loc as loc join fcc_en as en on loc.call_sign = en.call_sign
WHERE en.entity_name LIKE '%bubbah%' AND ST_Within(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(-115.29356182624997,36.13963970370481,-115.95274151374997,35.80622156767141,4326));
                 st_astext                 |      miles
-------------------------------------------+------------------
 POINT(-115.49475 35.8928055555556)        | 9.08012915615928
 POINT(-115.616388888889 35.8094444444444) | 11.2902759331815
 POINT(-115.616388888889 35.8094722222222) | 11.2883618698737
 POINT(-115.826805555556 36.1227222222222) |  15.378520803433
(4 rows)
```

Comment: What if the distance from A to B is R and from B to C is R and from C to D is R. And from A to D is 3R. Are A and D so close they should be merged? If so, you're probably looking for http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterWithin.html

Comment: Nice function. A and D don't need to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to round the coordinates for your select distinct. Depending on your CRS, the 3rd decimal place would be an accuracy of about 110 meters (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/52245) answer).

In your sample data, if we rounded to the 3rd decimal the second and third point would be identical. A simple way to do that is to typecast to numeric with 3 decimal places.

We can use SELECT DISTINCT ON () to select based on that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (ST_X::numeric(10,3), ST_Y::numeric(10,3)),
    st_astext(geom),
    ST_Distance(loc.geom::geography, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-115.62309833 35.97311)', 4326)::geography) / 1609.344 as miles
FROM fcc_loc as loc
JOIN fcc_en AS en
ON loc.call_sign = en.call_sign
WHERE en.entity_name LIKE '%bubbah%' AND ST_Within(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(-115.29356182624997,36.13963970370481,-115.95274151374997,35.80622156767141,4326));
```