# GPS accuracy threshold standard

Tags: gps, accuracy, standards

So obviously different applications would require different levels of accuracy, but I'm wondering if there's **some standard threshold that the field typically determines to be "good"** (or "*good enough*").

For example, if I'm trying to locate a tree in the woods, I'd probably need sub-meter accuracy or close to it in order to ever find that tree again. However, locating the crest of a mountain would likely only require accuracy to several meters b/c of it's conspicuousness in the landscape.

However, maybe in both applications some "generalized" accuracy threshold could be calculated as:

`grain size of object * xx% of that grain size`

So is there such a standard, or is it only up to the researcher to make that decision personally given the context?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience six decimal places is 'good enough' for most purposes at ~11cm accuracy, and I believe that to be the general opinion for most applications, but yes it probably depends on your requirements.

See the post below for some detail:

[Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)