# Resampling WGS84 to ETRS89 causes change in pixel dimension

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, resolution, distortion

I'm a first time QGis user and got some resolution troubles. I need to create a DEM for whole Europe using SRTM 1-arc second (30m) from USGS. As I need the slope algorithm in a later step, I have to use a cartesian coordinate system. I'd like to use one single system, so I guess I go with ETRS89 (instead of UTM zones). When I reproject to the new CRS, the pixel sizes change from 30x30m to 26x26m (according to the measuring tool).

Can somebody explain me why this happens and if it matters?

Answer (score 2):

The 30m is a rough estimation. The actual number of meters depends on the latitude. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208739 for some numbers.

PS: For Europe the EPSG:3035 "ETRS-LAEA" is recommended and widely used.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! ETRS89 is the same as EPSG:3035 but I'm glad to hear it's recommended.