# How to prevent Google My Maps from truncating lat long values

Tags: maps, google

My Lat and Long coordinates get truncated from 37.747574 and -25.675669 to
37.74757, -25.67566 when I import them into Google My Maps.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

As [this excellent question and answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) discuss the chances of your coordinates being accurate to 6 decimal places (10 cm) are very small so Google rounding them to 5dp (1m) are probably ignorable. If nothing else the accuracy of the surrounding map data and/or imagery is lower than that.