# PostGIS: Creating Polygon from lots of other geometries and then returning list of ID's in the same query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-query, aggregation, spatial-cluster

I am fairly new to all of this but in simplistic terms I have the following problem:
I need to create lines from points, and from said points group all of those within n distance of one another. From this grouping I need to return the concave hull nice and tight. This bit is easy but I need to retain an understanding of the attribution of the points I originally manipulated.

In the table I have the following:

point_1, point_2, ID_1, ID_2

from this I have designed the query for the aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT 
ST_AsText(
    ST_ConcaveHull(unnest(
        ST_ClusterWithin(
            ST_MakeLine(table.point_1, table.point_2),0.00010008999
        )
    ),0.99)::geometry
) AS aggr
FROM tb1 AS table
```

This appears to meet my requirements however how could I also return a list of all ID_1's and ID_2's whose geometries have gone through the aggregation process for example:

```
aggr            |    ID_1s    |    ID_2's    |
_____________________________________________

POLYGON(123...) | 1,2,3,4,5.. |  66,33,45...
POLYGON(566...) | 9,3,5,0,2.. |  21,53,65...
```

I have struggled to ask the question almost as much as I have to solutionize my problem (without success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) (follow the provided links for further details on the algorithm and the impact of the function arguments); as a [*Window function*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), it operates on the *input rows* within a defined frame, where it assigns cluster ids as column values:

```sql
SELECT  ARRAY_AGG("ID_1") AS "ID_1's",
        ARRAY_AGG("ID_2") AS "ID_2's",
        ST_ConcaveHull(
            ST_Collect(line),
            0.99
        ) AS aggr
FROM    (
    SELECT  "ID_1", "ID_2",   -- identifiers are lower-case unless wrapped with ""
            ST_ClusterDBSCAN(line, 0.0001, 1) OVER() AS _clst,
            line
    FROM    <your_table>,
            LATERAL ST_MakeLine(point_1, point_2) AS line
) q
GROUP BY
        _clst
;
```

---

A note on your calculated distance value:

Unless you are working with a nano tube mesh here, a precision of 6 decimal places is absolutely sufficient, and I even rounded it up to only 4 here; read one of the boards [most prominent answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/93656).

Comment: Wow, I would not have come up with this given the time I have given myself thank you. I am testing it through now, there are some mildly erroneous results in comparison to my previous query but that issue is likely related to the data. 
I will test and feed back. Thank very much!

Comment: thank you. I believe that the distance and min points are the wrong way round in ST_ClusterDBScan.

Comment: @Phish oooh, cr**, you are right, my mistake. I corrected that.