# Accuracy of latitude and longitude based on decimal places

Tags: latitude-longitude, accuracy, decimal-points

After reviewing various information regarding accuracy of latitude and longitude for specific decimal places, I have a question regarding the information that many have posted, such as in [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/65465#65465).

If my analysis and calculations are correct, it seems accuracy values that people reference for 6 decimal places upwards are not scaled correctly.  Is this a correct statement, or am I looking at this wrong?

For instance, many are saying 9 decimal places would be `111 μm`, but from my math:
`((111,111 m) / 10^9) * (1000 m / cm) * (1000 mm / cm) = 111 mm`.

This would be 1,000x larger than what many others are saying.  Where is the difference?

Comment: 100 cm/m, 10mm/cm

Comment: 111×10××6 mm / 10××9 = 0.111 mm

Answer (score 4):

There is 100 cm in a meter, not 1,000 and only 10mm in a cm, not 1,000. So you are 1,000 times out in your calculation.