# QGIS Vertex Editor - decimal places

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to change the number of shown decimal places for the coordinates in the `Vertex Editor` of QGIS 3.x?

[image]

So instead of displaying 9.4324, I want to have it to show me 9.4323669648.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but if 4 decimal may not provide the accuracy you need 10 decimal seem a bit to much and will be harder to read (check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude to help you determine how many decimal will be useful for you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of digits shown in `Vertex Tool` is tied to the value in your project settings:

Menu `Project`->`Properites`
`General` tab -> `Coordinate and Bearing Display`
Set `Coordinate precision` to `Manual` and input the number of decimal places you would like to be shown:

[image]

In this case I set it to 7 digits, and that is what I now see in `Vertex Tool`:

[image]

**Note 1**: you need to close and reopen `Vertex Tool` to view the change

**Note 2**: Not sure about the reasons why you need such an extreme number of decimal places, however consider this [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2170) as a serious reference about the reasonable number of decimal places to adopt ;) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this one solved my problem. FYI the value was just an example. I'm developing an application and wanted a way to identify vertices. However, the decimal places 4 was not enough for me.

Comment: I guess at least someone here on GIS SE went on a sat imagery of sort to look if at that very precise coordinate there was a treasure trove :D

Comment: For some reason, this does not work in QGIS 3.16.14, still displaying 3 decimal places. 

Also, I don't agree on your number of digits and meaning. For example, calculating the line length of 0.0001 degrees E/W yields 7.169 meters (WGS 84,  'LINESTRING (2 50, 2.0001 50)' ). This will of course vary depending on position.

For that reason we're using 7 decimal places in our case.

For a projected coordinate system, 3 decimals is more than enough in most cases.