# Why precision is reduced when I print the QgsGeometry points?

Tags: pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I was trying to extract latitudes and longitudes from `QgsGeomtery`. But I noticed that no all digits we being printed.

Can anybody identify why and how can I resolve this problem?

For example is this was the actual point 231233.22123413317891095, then output is 231233.2212341331.

This is the code used.

```
for part in geom.parts():
    for vertices in part.vertices():
        print(vertices.x(), vertices.y())
```

Comment: Everything beyond the third digit is unnecessary and unrealistic accuracy.

Comment: But in terms of lat longs it makes alot of difference.

Comment: That's not longitude or latitude, it's likely metres and I can guarantee you that your data is not accurate to < femtometre (10^-15). Just print to your desired precision `print(f"{vertices.x():.9f}")`

Comment: Even in lat/long the 10th digit does not make a big difference https://xkcd.com/2170/.

Comment: Please check this thread for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude