# can lat long of a place could have different precision from google maps

Tags: maps

When I select for `lat` `long` in google maps I could see the precision after decimal places are same for both,

for an instance a place could have `[12.941963598406998 {15} , 77.60827701942743 {15 ]`( both have 15, 15 after decimal) and `[12.94275476301649 {14} , 77.60185603753108 {14} ]`
(both have 14 , 14 after here).

Just wanted to check could there be a case where maps api can give different precision for `lat` and `long` something like `[12.9427547 {7} , 77.601856 { 6 }]` ( lat have 7 after decimal, and lng have 6).

Comment: Why should it matter? `77.601856 { 6 }` means the same than `77.6018560 { 7 }`.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't matter. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/8650/2856

Comment: got it thanks @user2856