# PostGIS: get Circle to GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, geojson, circle

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.global_circles (
   name character varying(64),
   geom circle);

INSERT INTO global_circles (name, geom) 
VALUES ('My circle', CIRCLE(POINT(16.56115880637268,46.959564402028334), 4000));
```

How can I get the "geom" value in GeoJSON format?

Comment: Your title and text disagree -- the CIRCLE type is not a PostGIS implementation.

Comment: @Koba Vince is correct Postgres has circle implemented but POSTGIS does not https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687546/749066

Comment: use `ST_BUFFER` instead

Comment: On a side note, have a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) about the accuracy of a coordinate

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, `circle` is a native postgres type that is not related to postgis. If using PostGIS, it is better avoid these native types.

That being said, if you really have to use the `circle` type, you can convert it to a native `polygon` which in turn can be converted to a postgis `geometry` and then can be exported as a geojson:

```sql
select st_asGeoJson(CIRCLE(POINT(16.56115880637268,46.959564402028334), 4000)::polygon::geometry);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            st_asgeojson                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-3983.438841194,46.959564402],[-3447.540456331,2046.959564402],[-1983.438841194,3511.06117954],[16.561158806,4046.959564402],[2016.561158806,3511.06117954],[3480.662773944,2046.959564402],[4016.561158806,46.959564402],[3480.662773944,-1953.040435598],[2016.561158806,-3417.142050736],[16.561158806,-3953.040435598],[-1983.438841194,-3417.142050736],[-3447.540456331,-1953.040435598],[-3983.438841194,46.959564402]]]}
(1 row)
```

PS: and of course this assumes that the radius is expressed in the same unit as the point coordinate, which seems unlikely with the given example.

---

If using a point in lat-long with a radius of 4000 meters, one way of doing it with PostGIS would be to cast to `geography` first:

```sql
select st_asGeoJson(St_Buffer(st_makePoint(16.56115880637268,46.959564402028334)::geography, 4000));
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    st_asgeojson                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[16.613712465,46.958835611],[16.612491754,46.951830285],[16.609299221,46.94512255],[16.604258179,46.938970016],[16.597562745,46.933608891],[16.58947033,46.929244935],[16.580291722,46.926045599],[16.57037918,46.924133621],[16.560112962,46.923582349],[16.549886822,46.924412934],[16.540092986,46.92659353],[16.531107204,46.9300405],[16.523274396,46.93462161],[16.516895464,46.940161074],[16.512215741,46.946446268],[16.509415535,46.953235867],[16.50860313,46.960269079],[16.509810522,46.967275657],[16.51299207,46.97398627],[16.518026136,46.98014287],[16.524719661,46.98550863],[16.532815529,46.989877084],[16.542002423,46.993080098],[16.551926824,46.994994372],[16.562206668,46.99554621],[16.572446128,46.994714373],[16.582250948,46.992530899],[16.591243707,46.989079863],[16.599078423,46.984494118],[16.605453903,46.978950156],[16.61012534,46.972661284],[16.612913687,46.965869389],[16.613712465,46.958835611]]]}
```

Comment: Thank you JGH for you answer. I have OpenLayers client side which allows you to draw circles and send them in geoJSON format to the database. At that point I could save them as polygons that look like circles. But when I then have to re-present those circles to the client from the DB, I will see them as polygons. This is a problem.

Comment: @Koba You can always extract the polygon boundary (in the DB) or draw only its edge (in the client)