# What does each number after decimal (0.0002311938) point in "Pixel Sixel" represent?

Tags: qgis

My understanding if I right-click a layer go to properties under "information" and scroll down to more information Pixel Size is that 0.00300000000,-0.003000000 (3) represents 3 centimeters per pixel. What is each unit right of the decimal?

Pixel Size 1.0 = 1 (?)
Pixel Size 0.3 = 3 (?)
Pixel Size 0.03 = 3 (?)
Pixel Size 0.003 = 3 (?)
Pixel Size 0.003 = 3 (?)
Pixel Size 0.0003 = 3 (?)
Pixel Size 0.00003 = 3 (?)

Comment: See https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/metric-si-prefixes. Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your horizontal units, which you *need* to know so check your metadata.

Assuming your horizontal units are metres (which is *not* a certainty as coordinates with decimal places tend to be decimal degrees, not metres or feet):

```
Pixel Size 1.0 = 1 m
Pixel Size 0.3 = 3 dm (decimetre) or 30 cm (centimetre)
Pixel Size 0.03 = 3 cm
Pixel Size 0.003 = 3 mm (millimetre)
```

Source: [SI prefixes](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html)

If they are decimal degrees, the length of one degree of longitude varies with latitude, but at the equator:

```
1.0 ~= 111 km 
0.1 ~= 11.1 km
0.01 ~= 1.11 km
0.001 ~= 111 m
0.0001 ~= 11.1 m
0.00001 ~= 1.11 m
```

See also [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/2856)