# Getting only short coordinates instead of full length coordinates

Tags: geoserver, polygon, openlayers, coordinates, features

I am working on OpenLayers6. And I want to show the plots.
But My plot data is not being rightly placed on original plot polygon.

What my concern is that I want to get the full-length coordinates, but getting only half coordinates data

Here is my Code from where i'm fetching the features of polygon.

```
var wmsSource = new TileWMS({
        url: "http://13.233.167.180:9090/geoserver/pinyard/wms",
        tileSize: 512,
        params: { LAYERS: "pinyard:home_plotmap", TILED: true },
        serverType: "geoserver",
        transition: 0.8,
      });
```

whenever the user clicks, I want to show the polygon features.
Here is the code of this.

```
map.on("singleclick", async function (evt) {
        // var element = popup.getElement();
        const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
        var url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          viewResolution,
          "EPSG:4326",
          {
            INFO_FORMAT: "application/json",
          }
        );

        if (url) {
          await fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              console.log(data);
              // I am getting data in console.
              // I am getting only short coordinates.

              if (data.features.length === 0) {
                overlay.setPosition(undefined);
              } else {

                const styles_green = [
                  new Style({
                    fill: new Fill({
                      color: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)",
                    }),
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                      color: "#ffcc33",
                      width: 2,
                    }),
                  }),
                  new Style({
                    geometry: function (feature) {
                      // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
                      const coordinates = feature
                        .getGeometry()
                        .getCoordinates()[0];
                      return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
                    },
                  }),
                ];

                const geojsonObject = {
                  type: "FeatureCollection",
                  crs: {
                    type: "name",
                    properties: {
                      name: "EPSG:4326",
                    },
                  },
                  features: [
                    {
                      type: "Feature",
                      geometry: {
                        type: "Polygon",
                        coordinates: [data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                };
```

My concern is I want to get the data in full coordinates like this:

```
[[72.59962347256743, 23.00193887325614],
[72.60040131318172, 23.00193887325614],
[72.60054078805076, 23.00196850066428],
[72.60099676358334, 23.00196850066428]]
```

But, I'm getting Coordinates like this:

```
[[72.5996, 23.0019],
[72.6004, 23.0019],
[72.6005, 23.0019],
[72.6009, 23.0019]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer allows you to how many decimal digits to use when outputting text coordinates on the [global settings page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#number-of-decimals). Be aware of using spurious amounts of precision when you don't have that much accuracy in your data. See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674) for more detail.

Comment: I like this one: https://xkcd.com/2170/