# st_generatepoint returns invalid memory alloc request size 4305734400

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

As a result of some analysis I am left with this polygon (there are probably others, but this is one example):

```
SELECT  st_astext(geom,1) FROM  flood.temp WHERE    id = 9695

POLYGON((29.8 52.2,29.8 52.3,29.8 52.3,29.8 52.2,29.8 52.2))
```

[image]

Note that there are, I think, many decimal points not being displayed by the PostgreSQL output on these points.

I've ran st_isvalid on it, and it is valid.

When I try to do this:

```
SELECT  st_generatepoints(geom,1) FROM  flood.temp WHERE    id = 9695
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 4305734400
```

I guess that the polygon is so 'thin' that putting a point on it's surface cannot be done? My question is how to elegantly deal with this. Is there a solution other than deleting these features? And if I should delete them, how do I identify them?

n.b. When I try to display this geometry in pgAdmin 7.4 it does not appear and says 'unsupported geometries are not supported', but viewing it in pgAdmin 7.6 it works (giving the image displayed above).

EDIT 1:

POLYGON((36.75 35.230555555555554,36.75 35.233333333333334,36.75000000000002 35.233333333333334,36.75000000000002 35.230555555555554,36.75 35.230555555555554))

Comment: Can you print the geometry out using `ST_AsText(geom, 15)`?

Comment: Added above under EDIT 1. It's not the exact same geometry (I couldn't find it again in the table as I changed the IDs), but the same problems occurs.

Comment: Does it actually work if you buffer it slightly?

Comment: Yes, if I buffer with 0.000001 then it works.

Comment: (Though that isn't going to be a 'solution' as st_generatepoints or st_pointonsurface could then feasibly put the point outside of the boundary of my original polygon, which is a problem. I'm leaning towards deleting all polygons below a certain size of say 0.0000001 . It won't effect my work. But it's an annoying bug (?).

Comment: Thanks, that reproduces the error.  I'll log this on the PostGIS issue tracker (https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis).

Comment: It may not be possible to create points which lie strictly within such a narrow polygon.  But at very least the function should not error out.

Comment: Ticket opened: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "polygon" is as thick as... [an atom](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)! No wonder why it is causing troubles.

Even being this thin, it remains a valid polygon though.

You can detect such entries by [snapping](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) their vertices to a grid, using a meaningful grid size, and excluding now [empty](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsEmpty.html) polygons

```sql
select ST_IsEmpty(
         st_snapToGrid(
           'POLYGON((36.75 35.230555555555554,36.75 35.233333333333334,36.75000000000002 35.233333333333334,36.75000000000002 35.230555555555554,36.75 35.230555555555554))'::geometry,
           0.0000001));
 st_isempty
------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ah that's a great way of detecting them. thanks. I did try 'st_snaptogrid' to try and detect them, but presumed it would return null if they were not valid anymore. I didn't realise to then run st_isempty afterwards to find them. Thanks.